# Sapply instead of ggplot2 loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, sapply

Can someone please help me to create an sapply that will perform these plots. I understand the ggplot2 does not support loops.

code:

```
library(ggplot2)

meanX <- 5
meanY <- 5

x <- sin(1:10)
y <- 30:21
Res <-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

for (i in 1:nrow(Res))
{
  ggplot(Res) + geom_point(aes(x = Res$x, y = Res$y)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = meanX, y = meanY, xend = Res$x[i], yend = Res$y[i]), Res )
}
```

Comment: You absolutely can use `ggplot()` inside a loop.  It's not always the fastest way to do things, but it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't need any loop. You could just do

```
ggplot(data = Res) +
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = meanX, y = meanY, xend = x, yend = y))
```